# Use Magento header and footer on a webpage inside Magento root Directory in Magento2

Tags: magento2, header, footer, external

I have a working web page which includes HTML and javascript.
I want to use Magento Header and Footer on that webpage.

Supposing that I kept that web page inside the Magento root directory, **What is the easiest way to Use Magento header and footer on external the webpage?**